# Size of wchar_t for unicode encoding

Tags: c++, unicode

is there 32-bit wide character for encoding UTF-32 strings? I'd like to do it via `std::wstring` which apparently showing me size of a wide character is 16 bits on windows platform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't be able to do it with `std::wstring` on many platforms because it will have 16 bit elements.

Instead you should use `std::basic_string<char32_t>`, but this requires a compiler with some C++0x support.

Comment: Beware! Remember that just because you're using a 32-bit encoding doesn't mean that you can assume that each code point represents one character! Be careful not to split composite characters. Depending what you're doing you may want to hunt up a library that will break your string down into grapheme clusters. See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29.

Answer (score 7):

The size of `wchar_t` is platform-dependent and it is independent of UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32 (it can be used to represent unicode data, but there is nothing that says that it represents that).

I strongly recommend using UTF-8 with `std::string` for internal string representation, and using established libraries such as ICU for complex manipulation and conversion tasks involving unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `typedef`!

It would look something like this:

```
typedef int char_32;
```

And use it like this:

```
char_32 myChar;
```

or as a c-string:

```
char_32* string_of_32_bit_char = "Hello World";
```

Comment: A signed type for Unicode data? Well, we put up with a possibly-signed one for UTF-8, but why?? Also, `"some string-literal"` doesn't have the type you need

Comment: Storing unicode characters in an implementation defined sized type, what could go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The modern answer for this is to use `char32_t` (c++11) which can be used with [`std::u32string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). However, in reality, you should just use `std::string` with a encoding like UTF-8. Note that the old answer to `char32_t` would be using templates or macros to determine which unsigned integral type has size of `4` bytes, and use that.